# Babel either works in edge and fails with jest or vice versa

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I am running a react app and just learned that it fails to load in Microsoft Edge.

In my babel config, here is what I had:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-react', ['@babel/preset-env', {
    targets: {
      node: "current"
    }
  }]],
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
};
```

My tests, run using Jest, worked without issue, so my CI/CD implementation (CircleCI and Heroku) worked as well.

To get my app working in Edge, I changed my babel config to this:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-react', ['@babel/preset-env', {
    targets: {
      "browsers": ["last 2 versions"],
      node: "current"
    }
  }]],
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
};
```

Now, Edge loads, but I receive an error when I run my tests.

```
● Test suite failed to run

ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

Here are my devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/node": "7.x",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.7.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3",
    "webpack": "^4.29.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
  }
```

I've spent about a day and a half trying to sort this out and haven't come across a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found:
https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/560

Install @babel/plugin-transform-runtime

Add it to your babel config plugins setting like so:

```
plugins: [["@babel/transform-runtime", {
    "regenerator": true
  }]]
```

Presets can remain the same:

```
presets: ['@babel/preset-react', ['@babel/preset-env', {
    targets: {
      "browsers": ["last 2 versions"],
      node: "current"
    }
  }]],
```